# Rxjs workflow for MongoDB Document References

Tags: mongodb, angular, ionic2, rxjs5

I am developing an application on Ionic2/rc0. I got a ReplaySubject on a singlenton service that keeps the current user consistent across the whole app. It all works fine, I can subscribe to it and get a User object as easy as

```
    this._user.Current.subscribe(user=>{ console.log(user)});
```

The User object looks like this

```
User {
    confirmed:true
    devices:["57f65werwe343bn8843f7h","7yr3243h5429hf2hjd"]
    friends:["t245y53h65346htyh","356ytrer75dfhg43we56df"]
    email:"francescoaferraro@gmail.com"
    id:"57f6525e926bbc7615fc5c5c"
    notification:false            
    password="$2a$04$.Fk/8eMj18ZrkfurbbdP4uT3yOs7Lb9db74GkNfgtABVY.ez2Q0I."
    picture:"https://api.cescoferraro.xyz/kitty"
    role:"master"
    username:"cesco"
}
```

As you can see my backend is using MongoDB with One-to-Many Relationships with Document References as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

I have created a devices tab where I want to display all data about those user devices, but I need to call this._devices.info for each one of current.devices and concat the result back to TrueDevices

```
@Component({
    template: `  
            <ion-header>
                <ion-navbar>
                    <ion-title>Tabs</ion-title>
                </ion-navbar>
            </ion-header>
            <ion-content>
                <h2>Device:list</h2>

                <h2 *ngFor="let item of devices | async">{{item}}</h2>

                <button ion-button (click)="readDevice()">Read Random Device</button>
            </ion-content>
`
})
export class DeviceComponent {
    devices: Observable<string[]>;
    TrueDevices: Observable<Device[]>;

    constructor(public _user: UserService, public _device: DeviceService) {

        this._user.Current.subscribe(user=>{ this.devices = Observable.of(user.devices)});

        // Get current User
        // call this._devices.info for each one of current.devices
        // concat the result back to TrueDevices
        this._user.Current
            .subscribe((result) => { console.log(result) });

    }

    readDevice(){
        console.log(this.devices);
        this._device.info(this.devices.value[0]).subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
    }
}
```

I will need to repeat the same procedure to the friends tab and so on. I am pretty sure there are a couple operators that would do the magic, but I am fairly new to rxjs and not familiar with all of them. Whats the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
this._user.Current
  .switchMap(user => Observable.from(user.devices)) // after this line, you have an Observable<string>
  .mergeMap(device => this._device.info(device)) // each device will be mapped to another observable(or stream), and all the streams will be merged together
  .toArray() // wait for all the streams to complete and reduce all the results into an array.
  .subscribe(array => console.log(array));
```

or go to the gitter room:
https://gitter.im/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS